# override func update problems, in swift

Tags: swift, if-statement, sprite-kit, game-physics, statements

I'm currently using the following code to monitor my game state:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    // Game over query //

    if car.physicsBody?.angularVelocity < 10  {carFly()}
    else {gameOver()}
}
```

This appears to work well and does not tax the CPU at all (which is pleasing). However, the function gameOver() is never called just once... It calls multiple times which leads to jerky transitions / weird behaviour.

How can structure this so that it calls gameOver() just once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `Bool` flag to control this situation like this for example:

```
...
var isGameOver: Bool = false
...
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    // Game over query //

    if car.physicsBody?.angularVelocity < 10  {
        carFly()
    } else {
        if isGameOver {
            return
        } else {
            isGameOver = true
            gameOver()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It flags the return statement as never going to be executed?

Comment: Cancel that, I placed isGameOver in the wrong place. This works perfectly, Thanks very much!